# Scala silhouette cannot authenticate

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

Using Scala Silhouette slick seed template I am trying to implement authentication in Play. On authentication (when you click sign in) - I get this error in console. Any ideas on where to proceed to fix this? I have to note I am fairly new to Silhouette and Scala system itself.

```
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.libs.functional.syntax.package$.functionalCanBuildApplicative(Lplay/api/libs/functional/Applicative;)Lplay/api/libs/functional/FunctionalCanBuild;
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.CookieAuthenticator$.<init>(CookieAuthenticator.scala:92)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.CookieAuthenticator$.<clinit>(CookieAuthenticator.scala)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.CookieAuthenticatorService.init(CookieAuthenticator.scala:229)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.CookieAuthenticatorService.init(CookieAuthenticator.scala:148)
    at controllers.CredentialsAuthController$$anonfun$authenticate$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(CredentialsAuthController.scala:72)
    at controllers.CredentialsAuthController$$anonfun$authenticate$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(CredentialsAuthController.scala:70)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
```

Method itself:

```
def authenticate = Action.async { implicit request =>
    SignInForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      form => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.signIn(form))),
      data => {
        val credentials = Credentials(data.email, data.password)
        credentialsProvider.authenticate(credentials).flatMap { loginInfo =>
          val result = Redirect(routes.ApplicationController.index())
          userService.retrieve(loginInfo).flatMap {
            case Some(user) =>
              val c = configuration.underlying
              env.authenticatorService.create(loginInfo).map {
                case authenticator if data.rememberMe =>
                  authenticator.copy(
                    expirationDateTime = clock.now + c.as[FiniteDuration]("silhouette.authenticator.rememberMe.authenticatorExpiry"),
                    idleTimeout = c.getAs[FiniteDuration]("silhouette.authenticator.rememberMe.authenticatorIdleTimeout"),
                    cookieMaxAge = c.getAs[FiniteDuration]("silhouette.authenticator.rememberMe.cookieMaxAge")
                  )
                case authenticator => authenticator
              }.flatMap { authenticator =>
                env.eventBus.publish(LoginEvent(user, request, request2Messages))
                env.authenticatorService.init(authenticator).flatMap { v =>
                  env.authenticatorService.embed(v, result)
                }
              }
            case None => Future.failed(new IdentityNotFoundException("Couldn't find user"))
          }
        }.recover {
          case e: ProviderException =>
            Redirect(routes.ApplicationController.signIn()).flashing("error" -> Messages("invalid.credentials"))
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

This is the line exception pins to -

```
env.authenticatorService.embed(v, result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Silhouette 3.0 and Play 2.5.3 incompatibility. After upgrading Silhouette to 4.0 Beta4 and some changes got it running.